# Pulling data from server with Android application

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with pulling data from the server in an Android application. It took a long time to load the data, note that it is only 5 rows, I guess in my case because I am pulling user picture in each for loop round. I don't know a better way, is there are any suggestions?

**Here is my code for doing it in background function:**

```
 protected ArrayList<User> doInBackground(Object... Void) {

        String response = performGetCall(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchAll.php", null);
        User user = null;
        ArrayList<User> listUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
        try {
            JSONArray allUsersData = new JSONArray(response);
            //list = ArrayUtil.convert(allUsersData);
            //Log.d("List", list.toString());
            for (int i=0, l=allUsersData.length(); i<l; i++) {
                JSONObject userData = allUsersData.getJSONObject(i);
                String imageName = userData.getString("imageName");
                Bitmap image = null;
                if (imageName != null) {
                    String imagePath = SERVER_ADDRESS + "pictuers/" + imageName;
                    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                    try {
                        URL imageUrl = new URL(imagePath);
                        conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
                        conn.setReadTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                        conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                        image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) conn.getContent(), null, null);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d("Image get exception:",e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        image = null;
                    }
                }else {
                    imageName = "";
                }


                user = new User(userData.getInt("user_id"), userData.getString("name"), userData.getString("userName"), userData.getString("email"),userData.getString("gender"),userData.getString("password"),userData.getString("phone"), imageName,image);
                    listUsers.add(user);
                    // Log.d("Rturned User: ",returnedUser.email);
                    //Log.d("Response", userData.toString());
            }
            return listUsers;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listUsers;

    }
```

Comment: Picasso , glide etc and etc

Comment: Volley provides a JSON Http call **and** an ImageLoader. Seems to be just what you need. No more AsyncTasks either!